# How to use recursion technique on the following code?

Tags: java, recursion

```
static void nLines(int n) {
  for (int i= 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework, what have you tried?

Comment: If n <= 0, return. Print your line, and call `nLines(n-1)`. The for loop is not necessary.

Comment: the idea is the recursion is not necessary, and every recursion can be represented as a loop. recursion is far more "expensive" than a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can recurse on `n`.

```
static void nLines(int n) {
 if( n <= 0) {
     return;
 } else {
     int x = n - 1;
     nLines(x);
     System.out.println(x);        
 }
}
```

You call the function like so:

```
nLines(n);
```

Comment: `nLines(2)` prints `-1 0 1`.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive function to print n lines:

```
static void nLinesRecursive(int n) {
    int next = n - 1;

    if (next >= 0) {
        nLinesRecursive(next);
        System.out.println(next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static void nLines(int n) {
    if (--n < 0) return;
    nLines(n);
    System.out.println(n);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    nLines(3);
}
```

output:

```
0
1
2
```